# droppable and draggle append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, droppable

I am trying to drag images onto the drop zone, then based on there data attribute append a div to the drop zone.

But at the moment its just appending the image and saying undefined is not a function. I then need to be able to drag the new divs around the drop zone

here is the html

```
<ul class="tab-list">
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/one.png" data-itemstate="rectangle" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/one.png" data-itemstate="circle" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/one.png" data-itemstate="triangle" />
                        </li>
</ul>
```

here is the js

```
    $('.tab-list img').draggable({
            helper: "clone",
        });

        $('#main').droppable({
            drop:function(event, ui) {
                var item = $(ui.draggable);

                console.log(item.data('itemstate'));

                if(item.data('itemstate') == 'triangle'){
                    var add = '<div class="triangle"></div>';
                }
                add.appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using jquery ui? You should probably create a fiddle just for easier debugging. jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/bqhhpwuq/

```
$('.tab-list img').draggable({
            helper: "clone",
        });

        $('#main').droppable({
            drop:function(event, ui) {
                var item = $(ui.draggable);

                var add;
                if(item.data('itemstate') == 'rectangle'){
                    add = '<div class="triangle"></div>';
                }
                $(this).append(add);
            }
        });
```

css:

```
img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

div{
    border:1px solid;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

#main{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Is that a coincidence that we both used google image source? hah

Comment: i use google logos in all fiddles most of others may do the same

Comment: Yes it would be my first source just funny that we both did :)

Comment: How do you take his accepted answer when I posted 10 minutes before him the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues. Here is a fiddle with some corrections and an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/woobntbL/1/

Your first problem is here

```
if(item.data('itemstate') == 'triangle'){
  var add = '<div class="triangle"></div>';
}
add.appendTo($(this));
```

Add is not defined where you are trying to use it and it also needs to be a jquery object if you are trying to use appendTo.

There are some other issues but my fiddle has corrections you will obv need to change it to suit your needs.